# Apply text to curve surface not working properly?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, text-object

I want to apply this text to my curve cylinder but it keeps looking strange. How do I make it to where the text is all even and perfectly curved across my surface?

[image]

[image]

Here's the shrinkwrap modifier

[image]

Also, after it is applied, I only want it to stay there and not move anywhere else. So how would I do that with these modifiers applied?

Comment: Try to position the text close and perpendicular to your surface. That way you will get less distortion.

Comment: I found a hacky way to do it with a bezier circle and padding my cylinder piece and rotating it until it matches, so it kinda works for now yet seems so extra for a simple curve text on surface when in photoshop I could make it in like 1 second

Answer (score 1):

Create text, convert to mesh, add simple deform modifier: bend

[image]

result:

[image]

Sometimes a remesh modifier before the bend is needed to get an even smoother result.

If you want to move the text with your cylinder, just parent your text to the cylinder (or just join the objects).